# Dojo request writes [object Object] to request

Tags: node.js, rest, post, dojo

I have a request as below:

```
request.post("/webappbuilder/rest/layerGroups/" + this.appId + "/save", {
                data: {groupInfo: this.groupInfo},
                headers: {
                }
            }).then(function (r) {
                console.log("The server returned: " + r);
                context.setting.destroyLayerSelector();
                context.setting.createGroupableLayerSelector(this.groupInfo);
                context._promptSaved();
            });
```

When I look at the serverside log I see that this object is accepted as {"groupInfo":"[object Object]"}. It writes [object Object] to  my this.groupInfo object.

What should I do to make the server accept the variable as a json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide an object as the `data` property, dojo assumes that you want to send the data as regular HTML form parameters to the server. Those parameters are just a list of plain key=value pairs.

So, if you want one such value to be a JSON representation of an object, you would have to do (note the **JSON.stringify**):

```js
request.post("/webappbuilder/rest/layerGroups/" + this.appId + "/save", {
    data: {groupInfo: JSON.stringify(this.groupInfo)},
    headers: {...}
}).then(...
```

However, this actually means the groupInfo is sent to the server like this:

```
groupInfo=%7B%22id%22%3A32%2C%22name%22%3A%22Group1%22%7D
```

On your server, you will then likely see something like:

```
 {"groupInfo": "{id:32,name:\"Group1\"}"}
```

So you see, the value is still just a string! Remember, HTTP parameters are just key=value pairs. Here, the key is groupInfo, and the value is a string which happens to contain JSON (but HTTP doesn't know that, so you will have to parse it yourself in your application).

However, a POST request doesn't have to be boring key=value pairs. The request body is just text, so we can put anything there: XML, JSON, you name it. We can tell the server what the format is with a Content-Type header. If your web application backend framework is clever, it may inspect the header and parse the request body into an object for you.

```js
request.post("/webappbuilder/rest/layerGroups/" + this.appId + "/save", {
    data: JSON.stringify( {groupInfo: this.groupInfo} ),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
}).then(...
```

Note that here, we have moved the JSON.stringify call so that it encloses the entire data object. That means the `data` property is actually a string, and dojo will use it as the request body directly. We have also provided the Content-Type header as a clue to the web server.

If you do not provide the Content-Type header, dojo will send the default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", even though your request body does not contain key=value pairs.